# difference between k - 1 and --k here, really don't understand

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> combine(int n, int k) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        if (n == 0) {
            return res;
        }
        List<Integer> cur = new ArrayList<>();
        helper(res, cur, n, k, 1);
        return res;
    }
    private void helper (List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> cur, int n, int k, int start) {
        if (k == 0) {
            res.add(new ArrayList<>(cur));
            return;
        }
        for (int i = start; i <= n; i++) {
            cur.add(i);
            helper(res, cur, n, k - 1, i + 1); // helper(res, cur, n, --k, i + 1)
            cur.remove(cur.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Java. In last line 5, when I change "k - 1" to "--k", then the results will be different, can someone help me please? I think they are the same, but results are different.

Result for "helper(res, cur, n, k - 1, i + 1);" : [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]

Result for "helper(res, cur, n, --k, i + 1)" : [[1, 2], [2]]

It's Leetcode 77. Combinations

Answer (score 5):

When you do --k, it updates the value of k. It is similar to

> k = k-1;

then you are sending updated k value.
When you simply send value k-1 it does not update the value. It just passes the value of k-1

Answer (score 2):

When you do `k-1` you send the result of that operation to `helper()` without changing `k`, but when you do `--k` you decrease the value of `k` each time through the loop and send that new value to `helper()`

So if k is 4 to start you will call `helper()` with k = 3 each time when doing `k-1`but with `--k` k will be 3, 2, 1,... each time

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question I would say the problem is the following:

When you put k-1 you are telling the program to take the value equivalent to k-1, yet k remains unchanged

On the other hand, when you write --k, you tell the program to reduce k value by 1 and then take that number, thus affecting to next loop because k has changed its value by k-1

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `--k` is that like other posters have said it changes the value. Take a look at this [page here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-incr-decr.html) for more info about Java side effects. The value of k in the scope of the entire program is changing when you use that decrement, and so all subsequent function calls are using the same value that quickly gets decreased to 0. In the `k-1` example you are sending in the value of k-1. A separate instance of the value of the `k` you send in is worked on in that stack call rather than reusing the same `k`.

Answer (score -1):

What occurs here is that you are using a pre-increment operator. So it increments before it evaluates (executes) the statement. While in using `k - 1` it evaluates after, while `--k` would change the value before it is passed as a parameter.

Comment: This is wrong, k -1 will be calculated before it is sent to the `helper` method

Comment: I phrased it in a confusing way, it is evaluated before it is sent to the helper but in the broader statement line it is evaluated after. `k = 5; k-1 = 4` 1 which is after what would be a pre-increment of `--k`, will clarify.